# Slice text in fragments with determined length

Tags: python, slice

Considering the text line with numbers, I want to slice it into pieces with ten characters but I want to accept the fragments with less then ten if they exist.

With my script, I can obtain four complete groups, using 10 as fixed length, but the last four characters are missed.

The correct output would be:

```
['0123456789', '0123456789', '0123456789', '0123456789', '0123']
```

But I just obtain this:

```
['0123456789', '0123456789', '0123456789', '0123456789']
```

Any suggestion to fix these line in order to get the expected result?

```
step = 10
seq = "0123456789012345678901234567890123"
parts = []
for i in range(len(seq)/step): 
    sub = seq[i * step: (i + 1) * step]
    parts.append(sub)
print parts
```

Comment: I think at least some of the answers to [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/312443/953482) allow for partial final chunks - try out a couple of those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify the `range` to advance by `step`:

```
step = 10
seq = "0123456789012345678901234567890123"
parts = []
for i in range(0, len(seq), step):
    sub = seq[i: i + step]
    parts.append(sub)
print parts
```

Output:

```
['0123456789', '0123456789', '0123456789', '0123']
```

Answer (score 2):

`range(len(seq)/step)` will return `[0, 1, 2]`, so you will only do 3 iterations of your loop.

You *can* modify it to add 1 as follows:

```
for i in range(len(seq)//step+1):
```

But if sequence is an exact multiple of `step`, this will result in the last element of your list being an empty string `''`. To fix that, you can either add an `if` statement to not append an empty string or compute the range differently. I recommend the following:

```
step = 10
seq = "0123456789012345678901234567890123"
parts = []
nSteps = len(seq)//step + (0 if len(seq)%step == 0 else 1)
for i in range(nSteps): 
    sub = seq[i * step: (i + 1) * step]
    parts.append(sub)
print(parts)
#['0123456789', '0123456789', '0123456789', '0123']
```

Another thing to note is that I am using `//` instead of `/` to denote integer division. This doesn't make a difference in python2, but the latter would break your code in python3. Similarly, I am using `print` as a function rather than a statement.

Comment: Note that, if len(seq) is a multiple of step, it will do an extra iteration. E.g. using `seq = "012345678901234567890123456789"` and `step=10` it returns `['0123456789', '0123456789', '0123456789', '']`

Comment: @franciscosollima yes I realized this and posted an update. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
step = 10
seq = "0123456789012345678901234567890123"
chunks = []
while len(seq) > 0:
   chunks.append(seq[:step])
   seq = seq[step:]
```

In each iteration, this is eating up the `step`-length beginning part of `seq` and appends it to the `chunks` list. Since `seq[:step]` also works if `len(seq) < step`, this also works fine in the last iteration, regardless of the length of the last portion.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try a condition that allows for the last case to show up:

```
step = 10
seq = "0123456789012345678901234567890123"
parts = []
for i in range(len(seq)/step): 
    if i> (len(seq)/step)*(step - 1):
        sub = seq[(i-1)*step:]
    else:
        sub = seq[i * step: (i + 1) * step]
    parts.append(sub)
print parts
```